# Javascript OR(||) like operator in Grails

Tags: grails

In Javascript, there is an operator like `||` in which you can assign another value if the first value is `false`.

eg:

```
var a = false || true; // this will be true
```

Can I achieve the same in Grails?

Comment: Here you will get your answer: http://docs.grails.org/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the groovy [elvis operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_elvis_operator) for this:

```
def a = false ?: true; // this will be true
//OR  Boolean
```

Comment: Cool! Working! Thanks!